# Azure Form Recognizer boundingBox result convert to XY coordination

Tags: azure, preview, opencv, azure-form-recognizer, python

I'd like to convert the result of Form Recognizer "boundingBox" to image coordinate to visualize overlay image and recognized data.
However, the boundingBox result looks like not a XY coordinate position such like this image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOEi5.png

I need left top (X1,Y1) and right bottom (X2, Y2) calculation rule of each boundingBox.

I also, made some calculation rule with Cognitive Service OCR and Text Recognition but not information about Form Recognizer.
I tried to find XY coordinate rule by minus or divided but not rules I got it.

This is result json data I got by sample image of Form Recognizer. But could not find a boundingBox rule from it.

```
Responsebody: {
  'status': 'success',
  'pages': [
    {
      'number': 1,
      'height': 792,
      'width': 612,
      'clusterId': 0,
      'keyValuePairs': [
        {
          'key': [
            {
              'text': 'Address:',
              'boundingBox': [
                57.3,
                683.0,
                100.5,
                683.0,
                100.5,
                673.7,
                57.3,
                673.7
              ]
            }
          ],
          'value': [
            {
              'text': '1020 Enterpirse Way.',
              'boundingBox': [
                57.3,
                672.2,
                153.1,
                672.2,
                153.1,
                658.8,
                57.3,
                658.8
              ],
              'confidence': 0.53
            },
```

I need left top (X1, Y1) and right bottom (X2, Y2) calculation rule of each boundingBox.

Thanks team.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand your question but isn't the boundingBox property exactly what you are looking for? The eight numbers represent X and Y for all the four corners of a text box.

Comment: Check out the official link regarding the bounding box. If that helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/faq?view=form-recog-3.0.0#what-is-a-bounding-box-

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced this confusion while working on Form Recognizer. It has the origin at the bottom left of the page.

```
// Azure Bounding box is like this                      0---->1
//                                                      |     |
//                                         Y            |     |
//                                         ↑            3<----2
//                                  Origin . → X



// Expected Bounding Box            Origin . → X
//                                         ↓            0---->1
//                                         Y            |     |
//                                                      |     ↓
//                                                      3<----2
```

The eight values are X,Y values of 4 points. You can choose 0th, 1st for top left and 4th, 5th for the bottom right corner.
If you want to normalize the coordinates keeping the values between 0 and 1, you will have to divide each pixel value by the width and height of the respective page.

Answer (score 1):

In the example:

```
'boundingBox': [
            57.3,
            683.0,
            100.5,
            683.0,
            100.5,
            673.7,
            57.3,
            673.7
          ]
```

It represents the vertices of the bounding box.

```
// Azure Bounding box:           (57.3,683.0) X1,Y1---->x2,y2(100.5,683.0)
                                                  |     |
                                                  |     |
                                 (57.3,673.7) X4,Y4<----x3,y3(100.5,673.7)
```

From the above example, (X1,y1) and (x3,y3) is chosen to draw a bounding box. The bounding box is very sequential in Azure it starts x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4. The first two value in the list is x1,y1, and 5th,6th is x3,y3.

Answer (score 0):

The 8 numbers represent 4 pairs of (x,y) coordinates of the bounding box corners in the following order: top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. The origin of the coordinates system is the bottom left of the page. For the key 'Address:' in your example, you have top-left (X1, Y1) = (57.3, 683.0) and bottom-right (X2, Y2) = (100.5, 673.7).

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a concrete example, consider the following input image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eRS6.jpg

[image]

Azure Form Recognizer returns the following bounding box and you can plot the bounding box using the following code snippet with `opencv-python`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
image = cv2.imread('adhar2.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
boundingBox = [42.0, 84.0, 227.0, 0.0, 246.0, 41.0, 61.0, 126.0]
pts = np.array(boundingBox, np.int32).reshape((-1,1,2))
image = cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0), 2)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,40))
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

with the following output image:

[image]